# If $X$ is separable space then $X^∗$ is separable in all topologies $\tau$ such that $(X^∗,\tau)^∗ =X$?

Tags: banach-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, duality

Let $(X,\|.\|_{X})$ be a separable Banach space and the associated dual space is denoted
by $X^*$. By $w^*$ we shall indicate the weak$-*$ topology on $X^*$.

Let $B_{X^∗}= \{x^∗ \in X^∗ : \|x^∗\|_{X^∗}\leq 1\}$. Since $X$ is separable, the set $B_{X^∗}$ furnished with the relative $w^∗-$topology is *compact* (by the Alaoglu theorem) and *metrizable* (see Theorem I.5.85). Note that
$$
X^*=\bigcup_{n}{nB_{X^*}}
$$
hence $X^∗_{w^∗}$ (the space $X^∗$ furnished with the $w^∗-$topology) is separable.

Can we say that :  $X^∗$ is separable in all topologies $\tau$ such that $(X^∗,\tau)^∗ =X$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Separability of a locally convex space is equivalent to the existence of a dense countable-dimensional subspace. All compatible topologies for a dual pair (i.e. those that give the same continuous linear functionals) agree on the closures of convex sets.

Comment: can you  give me a book containing this result? please

Comment: I had to search for one, but according to Google Books (I don't own the book), it appears in section 2.5 of Barrelled Locally Convex Spaces by Carreras and Bonet.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Cameron, for your efforts.